# Node.js console.log() in txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, console.log, logfile

I have another question ([last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218868/how-do-i-export-an-array-with-module-exports-in-node-js)). At the moment i am working on a Node.js project and in this I have **many** console.log() functions. This has worked okay so far but I also want everything that's written to the console to *also* be written in a log-file. Can someone please help me?

For example:

```
Console.log('The value of array position [5] is '+ array[5]);
```

In my real code its a bit more but this should give you an idea.

Thank you hopefully.

Comment: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-logging-tutorial/ 
https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would use a library instead of re-inventing the wheel. I looked for a `log4j`-type library on npm, and it came up with https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node

if you want to log to the console and to a file:

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.configure({
  appenders: [
    { type: 'console' },
    { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/cheese.log', category: 'cheese' }
  ]
});
```

now your code can create a new logger with

```
var logger = log4js.getLogger('cheese');
```

and use the logger in your code

```
logger.warn('Cheese is quite smelly.');
logger.info('Cheese is Gouda.');
logger.debug('Cheese is not a food.');
```

Comment: will this log all the console logs without any need to add a custom console log for your particular module?

Comment: Didn't test this yet when i did i will tell you.

Comment: @Juan no, you need to get `var logger = log4js.getLogger('cheese');` and then you can do `logger.warn('Cheese is quite smelly.');`, `logger.info('Cheese is Gouda.');
`, etc.

Answer (score 76):

Just run the script in your terminal like this...

```
node script-file.js > log-file.txt
```

This tells the shell to write the standard output of the command `node script-file.js` to your log file instead of the default, which is printing it to the console.

This is called [redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) and its very powerful. Say you wanted to write all errors to a separate file...

```
node script-file.js >log-file.txt 2>error-file.txt
```

Now all `console.log` are written to `log-file.txt` and all `console.error` are written to `error-file.txt`

Comment: Note: two greater than signs redirect and appends the output to a file whilst a single greater than sign empties / overwrites the file upon a restart of your script. Example: `2>>error-file.txt`. I use two greater than signs to prevent a loss of output when restarting my scripts.

Comment: how to navigate it back to console?

Comment: @Angelzzz `node script-file.js 2>&1 | tee log-file.txt`

Comment: how can I insert line break in the txt file using this way?

Answer (score 21):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const myConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream('./output.txt'));
myConsole.log('hello world');
```

This will create an output file with all the output which can been triggered through `console.log('hello world')` inside the console.

This is the easiest way to convert the `console.log()` output into a text file.`

Comment: it logs undefined for a JSON. I tried `JSON.stringify()` but still got undefined

Comment: Hi Sarneet ,                                                                                                `const fs = require("fs");
const out = { name: "test", id: 456 };
const myConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream("./output.json"));
myConsole.log(out);
`                                                                                                                               the above code has worked for me without any issue . it was able to output json on a output file.

Comment: I am not able to change my vote. This did work for me when I tried it with a different CSV.

Answer (score 12):

You could try overriding the built in `console.log` to do something different.

```
var originalLog = console.log;

console.log = function(str){
  originalLog(str);
  // Your extra code
}
```

However, this places the `originalLog` into the main scope, so you should try wrapping it in a function. This is called a closure, and you can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
(function(){
   var originalLog = console.log;

  console.log = function(str){
  originalLog(str);
  // Your extra code
})();
```

To write files, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js) stackoverflow question, and to override `console.log` even better than the way I showed, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277780/can-i-extend-the-console-object-for-rerouting-the-logging-in-javascript). Combining these two answers will get you the best possible solution.

Answer (score 6):

Just write your own log function:

```
function log(message) {
   console.log(message);
   fs.writeFileSync(...);
}
```

Then replace all your existing calls to `console.log()` with `log()`.

Comment: What a brilliant idea, no stuffing around with winston or other over-engineered bloat; I'd probably use no args, and try to retrieve them inside the log function.

Answer (score 6):

@activedecay's answer seems the way to go. However, as of `april 30th 2018`, I have had trouble with that specific model (node crashed due to the structure of the object passed on to `.configure`, which seems not to work in the latest version). In spite of that, I've managed to work around an updated solution thanks to `nodejs` debugging messages...

```
const myLoggers = require('log4js');

myLoggers.configure({
    appenders: { mylogger: { type:"file", filename: "path_to_file/filename" } },
    categories: { default: { appenders:["mylogger"], level:"ALL" } }
});
const logger = myLoggers.getLogger("default");
```

Now if you want to log to said file, you can do it just like **activedecay** showed you:

```
logger.warn('Cheese is quite smelly.');
logger.info('Cheese is Gouda.');
logger.debug('Cheese is not a food.');
```

This however, will not log anything to the console, and since I haven't figured out how to implement multiple appenders in one logger, you can still implement the good old `console.log();`

PD: I know that this is a somewhat old thread, and that OP's particular problem was already solved, but since I came here for the same purpose, I may as well leave my experience so as to help anyone visiting this thread in the future

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution for file logging
[@grdon/logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grdon/logger)

```
const logger = require('@grdon/logger')({
  defaultLogDirectory : __dirname + "/logs",
})
// ...
logger(someParams, 'logfile.txt')
logger(anotherParams, 'anotherLogFile.log')
```