# i cant visit the message that i sent with getupdates in telegram bot

Tags: bots, telegram

I can't visit the message that I sent with `getupdates` in telegram bot

https://api.telegram.org/bot............./getupdates

how can I visit the messages that I sent with my **telegram bot**?

I want to show the messages that send with a bot with `sendmessage`  method but I couldn't find it

I can find my the `message_id` between sent messages but I can't visit the message that bot sent

Comment: Updates only contains message you received, not for your bot log.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I couldn't extract in which language you are coding your telegram bot.

In node.js for example, using [this](https://github.com/Naltox/telegram-node-bot) package, every message you sent is automatically written to the console. If you only want to review your message that should already do the trick. If you need to store it permanently you'd need to either try to find where the console.log happens and apply your own code or save the console output to a file (like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232578/node-js-console-log-in-txt-file)). Later on you could for example apply a regex to filter the needed messages.

Note: If you are not using any programming language yet (and are just sending to the telegram API URLs) you have no easy possibility of reviewing your sent messages apart from intercepting the HTTP packets.