# How can I change the output of the console in javascript to a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I change the output of the console in javascript to a file? I want to do this like in java. How can I do this? I want the logs to end up in a file instead of in the console. I need this for all of my dependencies.

[Node.js console.log() in txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232578/node-js-console-log-in-txt-file) does not help. My project is a dependency itself.

Comment: Maybe by overriding console.log implementation with `console.log = writeToFile` or something?

Comment: But the problem is he need to call/replace new overrided function everywhere. @AllanJuan

Comment: You really haven't explained why the other answer showing you how to do an override doesn't help. What did you try and what differed from expectations? I suspect you will have a very difficult time trying to only override some logging and not all of the app above your package as well